# Change File System of Internal Storage to EXT4

Tags: file-system, ext4

I have an Ainol tablet Novo 7, which has 16GB internal storage in FAT32 format. Due to the file system restriction, it can accept up to 4GB file size only. How can I format the internal storage to EXT4, which I can put bigger files inside?

Can't use MicroSD, as the slot is damaged / broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Install twrp recovery (google it)
2. Boot into recovery
3. Go to wipe -> advance wipe -> select the system partition -> change file system -> select ext4 format
4. Done